# How to get "extended properties" of Access DB Using OLEDB or ADO connection

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to access MS-Access DB extended properties like Author,Owner, Last Modified Date, Last Accessed Date etc. using vb.net.

Please help me on this issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access/create/modify different types of properties.

**at the database level**

1. Some of them are specific to the
   Access database object / Access mdb file and can be
   managed through JET engine only / DAO database object. Please see the "createProperty" method in VBA/Access Help.
2. Some properties are available at the
   database level through the ADOX
   object, and can be accessed through
   an ADO connection, as long as the
   connection provider supplies these
   properties: dateModified and
   dateCreated should then be available
   at the table\view\proc level.
3. When manipulating DAO recordsets
   (not ADO ones), some extra
   properties are available at the
   recordset level, like "lastUpdated"
   or "lastModified".

**At the file level**

4. Some of them are specific to the
   fileSystem object, available with
   VB. They are available at the file
   level only
5. You can manage\define extended
   properties at the file\document
   level through the DSOfile object
   (please google for more details).
   Such object will allow you to add as
   many properties as needed such as
   "Title", 'Author", "Subject" , etc.

So, depending on the kind of property you need to access, these might not be available through an ADO connection.